# How to animate size on these nested div elements? (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I created a spinning gear with [CSS animations](http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/wJAip). Now I want the entire spinning gear div to animate in from `1%` to `110%` to `100%` then back down to `1%`. Or basically `1px` to `90px` to `80px`(normal size) then back down to `1px`.

Right now the jQuery I'm using on the elements inside the `#spinner` div is animating it, but it's still off. The animation should act like CSS transition scale, where it zooms up from 1% to 110%. At the moment my animation is off center.

Any thoughts?

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/d7UjD/681/**
**NEW CodePen: http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/wJAip**

Would I have to animate each element in the `#spinner` div?

[image]

---

jQuery for Zoom in and out Animations:

```
function firstAnimate() {
    $('#spinner').animate({width: "110px", height: "110px"}, secoundAnimate);
}

function secoundAnimate() {
    $('#spinner').animate({width: "80px", height: "80px"}, 'slow', thirdAnimate);
}

function thirdAnimate() {
    $('#spinner').animate({width: "1px", height: "1px"}, 'fast', fourthAnimate);
}

function fourthAnimate() {
    $('#spinner').hide;
}

firstAnimate();
```

My spinning gear HTML:

```
<div id="spinner">
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="http://leongaban.com/_codepen/whoat/loader-logo.png"/>
    </div>
    <div id="gear" class="spin">
        <img src="http://leongaban.com/_codepen/whoat/loader-gear.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#spinner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px; height: 80px;
    top: 35%; left: 50%;
    margin-left: -40px;
    background: blue;
}

#logo {
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 80px; height: 80px; z-index: 3;
}

#logo img { width: 100%; height:100%; }

#gear {
   position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.1s;
   transition: transform 0.1s;
   -webkit-transform: translateX(100%) translateY(-100%) rotate(45deg);
   transform: translateX(100%) translateY(-100%) rotate(45deg);
   z-index: 2;
}
#gear img { display:block; }
```

Comment: $('#spinner').children().animate() try this i tried on fiddle its getting closer. Put some thought and u can achieve it. The children of div are not animating either animate them by individual selection or together.

Comment: I'd use CSS's `transform: scale` for this, it'd make it super simple

Comment: Thanks! Getting closer :) http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/wJAip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use a combination of CSS scale and jQuery to get the effect I wanted.

Scale does a much better job of scaling up from the center effortlessly, thx @Zeaklous

http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/wJAip

Needed a class to animate up and one to animate down:

```
.animateUp {
    -webkit-animation: animateUp .5s ease-in-out;
    animation: animateUp .5s ease-in-out;
}
.animateDown {
   -webkit-animation: animateDown .5s ease-in-out;
   animation: animateDown .5s ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animateUp { 
    0%  {
        -webkit-transform: scale(.1);
       transform: scale(.1);
    }
    70% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animateDown { 
    0%  {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(.1);
    }
    100% { 
        -webkit-transform: scale(.1);
        transform: scale(.1);
    }
}
```

The the jQuery, so I could control when it animates in and out:

```
$('#animate-up').unbind('click').bind('click', function() {
    $('#spinner').removeClass('animateDown');
    $('#spinner').addClass('animateUp');
    console.log('animate up');
});

$('#animate-down').unbind('click').bind('click', function() {
    $('#spinner').removeClass('animateUp');
    $('#spinner').addClass('animateDown');
    console.log('animate down');
});
```